# IIS Windows 2012 UrlRewrite and HTTPS

Tags: iis, https, iis-7.5, http-proxy

i'm USING Windows 2012 + IIS + UrlRewrite with a "Reverseproxy" Rule.
I've got an internal website : w3x.local

If i create a rule to "proxy" http://www... > http://www....local, works well!

If i create a rule to "proxy" https://www.. > http://www....local, seems that the website loses all CSS.

This is the web.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.w3x.local/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, SOLVED.

Wordpress need to make two changes, very important.

The first is to add the directive: $ _SERVER ['HTTPS'] = 'on'; .... to wp-config.php. This feature enables support for SSL

The second is "research", in the files of our graphic theme, all occurrences http: // and convert them to https: //
This is only necessary (and especially) for the use of the FONT and / or functions of Google.

Any reference like this: https // fonts.googleapis.com / css? Fam ....
must be converted to: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?fam